# Using django objects.filter to filter on db with a datetime field but for date only and based on local time not UTC

Tags: python, django, datetime

EDIT:
I am trying to get the checkins and checkouts for a current day.  The code I have is this:

```
def select_users():
    currentTime = dt.now()
    today = dt.today()    
    midNight = dt.combine(today, dt.min.time())
    print(currentTime)
    loggedIn = OnSiteLog.objects.filter(autoCheckin=False, checkIn__gte = midNight, checkOut__lte = currentTime).count()
```

It gives me a warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1421: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField OnSiteLog.checkOut received a naive datetime (2020-09-22 21:34:55.366769) while time zone support is active.
    
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1421: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField OnSiteLog.checkIn received a naive datetime (2020-09-22 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1421: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField OnSiteLog.checkOut received a naive datetime (2020-09-22 21:38:11.660009) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
```

I know all my data in the checkin and checkout is stored as UTC.  I am just not sure how to query to just give me all the checkins from midnight on a day, till 11:55pm on the same day.

(almost 24 hours time)

Comment: so you want to filter objects by specific UTC day? e.g. whole 23rd of September 2020

Comment: your question is confusing you should rewrite it more clearly especialy part about roll over( what you expect to get in that situation), if you save data in database in UTC why don't you just convert your local time to UTC time and query with it

Comment: updated to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the timezone doc "When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms." You don't have to worry about the UTC in the dabase when setting the timezone correctly in the config file.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: So I believe I have done this which if that is the case then all I am not sure about is how to filter on the checkin or checkout fields (both datetimeobjects) but only on Day itself (ignoring time)

Comment: You can filter like this  "OnSiteLog.objects.filter(autoCheckin=False, checkIn__date__gte = midNight, checkOut__date__lte = currentTime).count()" using "checkIn__date" you will be able to filter by date only